# HELP my very newly adopted cat hasn’t eaten, drinkin and pooped in the first 12 hours

Tags: cats, behavior, diet, adoption

My new adopted cat Luna hasn’t done any of the three things listed above she’s hiding under my bed and growls and hisses whenever she sees me or my feet if she doesn’t eat within 24 hours should I be attempting to get her back in the carrier and return her? Or are there some ways I can help her other than just leaving her alone

Comment: Does she have access to food and drink while you leave her alone? Does she eat when you are not around? How long did you leave her alone for so far?

Comment: how old is your cat,do not think about returning the cat until you learn to now her and she learns to know you.

Comment: We didn’t have a second bath room like what was suggested so I figured if she was under my bed and left alone she would be happy than if I was at my desk and not looking at her and leaving her alone and there is something in the way of the food and water so she wouldn’t be exposed to me, then she would still be able to hide and get a sense for the environment.

Comment: @Robbihurdman when i say alone in my answer it means no people or other pets in the same room,this is only for a short time until your cat gets less scared of the new area.

Comment: Have you tried feeding your new kitty wet food?  I had a kitten who didn't seem to eat for a while after bringing her home, but once I got her some wet food, she happily ate it up.

Answer (score 7):

It is scary for a cat to come to a new place and she will need some time to get over this.

Place food and water close to where she is hiding,but not in a corner of the room,she does not want to be cornered when she is as scared as she is now.

Place her litterbox in an area where she have the option to escape in atleast two directions if possible remove the lid of the litterbox(you can move the food and litterbox after she gets more comfortable in her new home).

Do your best to leave her alone for atleast two hours before you check in on her to see how she is,She needs to calm dow at her own pace.

She will most likely eat and drink when the night comes and your house is quiet,If she does not start eating and drinking by tomorrow you need to take her to a vet.

Try not to stress her or yourself this will end well for you and your cat,just give her the time she need.

Comment: Also take her to a vet if she doesn't urinate by tomorrow. It's normal for cats when introduced to a new place to not eat, drink, or eliminate for hours due to stress, but the not drinking or urinating especially can be harmful.